# How do I stop Access from auto sorting my data on import?

Tags: excel, sorting, ms-access, import, ms-access-2010

I am importing an Excel spreadsheet into Access 2010. I created a Saved Import that will import a column of data *intentionally* out of order. The query I created needs to take the exact order of this data, return a value associated with it from a master table in our company's DB, then allow me to export both of these fields to Excel. I need to do this because I need to copy and paste the export on top of the values of another spreadsheet.

The problem is that when I import into Access the FG column is sorted by A-Z. This can be seen in both the table import and the results of the query. How do I keep my data in the mixed up order throughout the whole process?

**Prepared Import sheet**

```
FG
D
B
E
A
C
```

**After importing**

```
FG
A
B
C
D
E
```

**Query**

```
FG         Description
A          descript of A
B          descript of B
C          descript of C
D          descript of D
E          descript of E
```

Comment: A table is an unordered "bag 'o data".  If you want a specific order for your rows, include a field or fields which you can use to specify that order.  An autonumber field might suit.

Comment: @HansUp Other way around - I want my table to **stay unsorted** but it keeps sorting it for me. When I compile the import spreadsheet I paste values in a _random_ order - I want them to stay in this same _random_ order

Comment: I suspect we're not talking about the same thing.  I thought you want the rows to be presented in the same order as they were originally stored.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The end goal of this whole thing is to export in the order D, B, E, A, C simply because that is the order in which I imported the values. However, when I import, my table becomes a sorted "bag 'o data" instead of unsorted. I'm leaning towards this being some default property because Microsoft is trying to be helpful.

Comment: But there is no way Access can reliably show you the data in the order in which it was stored ... unless you have some other field(s) which recorded that order.  If you don't include such a provision which you can use to explicitly define the order of retrieved rows, ordering is a crapshoot.

Comment: That worked! I used the option "Let Access create a primary key for me" when importing and it created the autonumber field. This sorted the table, but the query was still not sorted. I simply added the new ID field to my query and it maintained the "unsorted" order. @HansUp Please feel free to write it as an answer because that was the correct solution :) And thanks again for your continued assistance!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I had to use the option "Let Access create a primary key for me" when importing. This allowed the table to be populated with the data in the same order as was on the import spreadsheet. To make sure the query also keeps this same order, I had to include the new "ID" field as part of the results.

**Final SQL Code**

```
SELECT FGImport.ID, FGImport.FG, dbo_Active_Part_Number_List_Syteline.description
FROM dbo_Active_Part_Number_List_Syteline RIGHT JOIN FGImport ON dbo_Active_Part_Number_List_Syteline.item = FGImport.FG
GROUP BY FGImport.ID, FGImport.FG, dbo_Active_Part_Number_List_Syteline.description;
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be an OLD post, but I would suggest opening Excel and creating a simple macro to enumerate the records before importing to Access; once you've imported the file, this enumartion (we'll call it "MacroField") will be part of the data set you import (We'll call this table "Table1"). You'll still retain the records original formatting by querying the record and ordering by Table1.MacroField asc/desc.  There has to be a better way of doing it, but if you're in a pinch this does the trick.

---

Sub liminal()

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

```
If Sheets(i).Name <> "PrimaryTab" Then
    ct = 0
    Sheets(i).Activate
    Range("B1000000").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    en = ActiveCell.Row

        For p = 1 To en
            ct = ct + 1
            Sheets(i).Range("A" & p).Value = ct
        Next p

End If
```

Next i
Sheets("PrimaryTab").Range("A1").Select
MsgBox "Data Set, please open and load to MS ACCDB"
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import an Excel table (let's say with three columns) and you want the first row of the Access table (you are importing the data into) to have the Columns Title, then you create and Access table "myTable" with these fields:

```
F1 (Data Type: whatever)
F2 (Data Type: whatever)
F3 (Data Type: whatever)
Order (Data Type: AutoNumber)
```

In Access VBA you will use the following command:

```vb
ImportFile = "C:\myExcelFile"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "myTable", ImporteFile, False
```

When the Excel file is imported, the data will be alphabetical sorted by the first column; but the Field "Order" will have the sequential order of the data as in the Excel File.  You can use a query on the table to sort the data by the field "Order", thus getting back the same data arrangement as in the Excel Table.